# How to Show Progress bar while executing model in controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, progress-bar

I know PHP cannot show progress bar while executing something on server, but AJAX can.
the question is, how do I do that ?
and where should I put the script code ?
.
here is my controller

```
public function unggah_data() {

$this->load->model('Wsimport_model');

$this->Wsimport_model->ws_mahasiswa($tahunmhs, $databasemhs);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_idmahasiswa($tahun, $databaseidmhs);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_dosenpt($tahun, $databasedosenpt);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_ajardosen($tahun, $databaseajardosen);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_kelaskuliah($tahun, $databasekelaskuliah);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_kurikulum($tahun, $databasekurikulum);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_matakuliah($tahun, $databasematakuliah);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_matakuliahkurikulum($tahun, $databasematakuliahkurikulum);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_nilai($tahun, $databasenilai);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_akm($tahun, $databaseakm);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_dayatampung($tahun, $databasedayatampung);
$this->Wsimport_model->ws_bobotnilai($tahun, $databasebobotnilai);

redirect('operator_pt/Wsimport_data');   
}
```

I want to show to the client that the model is executed one by one with progress bar and some text.
The view is just a basic form with POST method ..

Comment: Serverside and client side is completely different thing. while you raise any request and which is processing by your server then server wait for complete request processing after it gives response which is completely on new dom.. in ajax case. ajax refer same dom so you can call any loader before ajax call and stop it after complete it but for server it wont. so i think you want that feature then change your logic